# How to display the neighbouring values of an array element that uses randomly generated ints?

Tags: java

This is the code i have so far and i am wondering how to find the value that has been chosen by the randomInt, print it, and then find the neighbouring values.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private static final int ROWS = 5;
    private static final int COLS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum1 = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int Counter = 0;
        int[][] array = new int[ROWS][COLS];
        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.println("\nGenerated numbers:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = random.nextInt(100);
                System.out.printf("%4d", array[i][j]);         
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        int row = random.nextInt(ROWS);
        int col = random.nextInt(COLS);
        System.out.printf("\nRow: %d, Column : %d\n", row, col);
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Row " +row );
        System.out.print(" and Column " +col );
        System.out.println(" will select value: "  );
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" Numbers to consider: ");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to print `array[row][col]`.  The neighboring values will be in positions like `array[row-1][col]`, `array[row][col+1]`, and so on -- the ones with a next-higher or lower row or column.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for such a quick and simple answer, I struggle alot with java so apologies if it is a stupid question.

Comment: Also is there a certain step you have to take if you wanted to sum all the values up and/or get the average?

Comment: Sure.  `array[row][col] + array[row][col-1] + ...`